# jquery ajax sucess data into facebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, facebox

UPDATE: The code if working I has some css issues.

I'm trying to put ajax data into facebox modal box, I have the  following code but facebox modal box is not loading. Looking into firebug ajax is returning the correct data but i do not know how to pass that data to facebox.

```
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').live("click", function() { 

    var ajaxpostID=$(this).parent().attr("id"); //Get entry ID

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.someurl.com/ajax/facebox-ajax.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: ({
                ajaxpostID: ajaxpostID
            }),
            success: function(data) {
                $.facebox(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                $.facebox('There was an error.');
            }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this worked for me:

```
//added some id to anchor tag and 
$('a[id='some_anchor_id']').live("click", function() { 
    var ajaxpostID=$(this).parent().attr("id"); //Get entry ID

    jQuery.facebox(function() { 
        var form_data = {
            ajaxpostID: ajaxpostID
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.someurl.com/ajax/facebox-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery.facebox(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                $.facebox('There was an error.');
            }
            )
        });
    })
})
```

Hope it works for you